# Cygwin ::stat() giving 'No such file or directory' for samba mounted cygdrive

Tags: c++, cygwin, porting, samba, stat

I have some code calling ::stat() on a pathname which works fine on Centos, but on Cygwin, it fails when the supplied pathname is a directory on a samba mounted drive:

```
struct stat info;

int result1 = ::stat("/cygdrive/h/", &info)
int errno1 = errno;
int result2 = ::stat("/cygdrive/", &info)
int errno2 = errno;
```

With this, I can see the values:

```
result1 == -1
errno1 == 2
result2 == 0
errno2 == 0
```

How can I stat() a samba mounted drive successfully from Cygwin?

Comment: What happens if you stat `"/cygdrive/h/."`?